# Laravel: Cookie::forget() is not removing cookie, but setting value to null

Tags: laravel

I have functionality to check for a certain cookie. If it exists and is of a certain value, the user will be redirected someplace else and once they're redirected, the cookie should be forgotten.

Here is the functionality that handles this on my Controller:

```
 /**
     * Set plan intent either to query param or cookie
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function setPlanIntentCookie() {
        $this->plan_intent = Cookie::get('rh_plan_intent');
    }


    /**
     * Returns all the data needed for the paywall
     */
    public function paywall() {
        $this->setPlanIntentCookie();

        if ($this->plan_intent == "free") {

            $account = auth()->user()->accounts->first();
            $account->update([
                'trial_ends_at' => now()->addDays(30),
            ]);

            return redirect()->route('home')
                ->withCookie(Cookie::forget('rh_plan_intent'));

        }

     // rest of code isn't reached during this test
     ...

}
```

My test:

```
/**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_user_with_free_trial_cookie_will_skip_paywall_and_begin_trial() {
        $this->disableCookieEncryption();
        $this->actingAs($this->user);

        $this->withCookie('rh_plan_intent', 'free')
            ->get(route('paywall'))
            ->assertRedirect(route('home'))
            ->assertCookieMissing('rh_plan_intent');


        $this->account->refresh();
        $this->assertNotNull($this->account->trial_ends_at);

    }
```

This fails

```
Cookie [rh_plan_intent] is present on response.
Failed asserting that Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie Object &0000000064bec37e0000000044e2323c (
    'name' => 'rh_plan_intent'
    'value' => null
    'domain' => null
    'expire' => 1431023770
    'path' => '/'
    'secure' => null
    'httpOnly' => true
    'raw' => false
    'sameSite' => null
    'secureDefault' => false
) is null.
```

so Cookie::forget() seems to be changing the value from `free` to `null`? I want to remove the cookie entirely.

Edit: I just checked laravel's source code and what `forget` does:

```
public function forget($name, $path = null, $domain = null)
    {
        return $this->make($name, null, -2628000, $path, $domain);
    }
```

So it does just make the value null. How can I delete?

Comment: There is no "unsetcookie" function even in raw PHP. Actually, it is a proper way to get rid of the cookie. I suggest to consider using `assertCookieExpired`.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up using `assertCookieExpired` instead.